# RxJava2 + Retrofit2: Почему в интерфейсе Retrofit часто используют именно Observable/Flowable?

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Читал разные статьи и смотрел много видео на ютубе по связке RxJava и Retrofit, и очень часто видел примерно одну и ту же конструкцию:

```
@GET("some/endpoint")
fun getSomeData(): Observable<SomeData>
```

И я никак не могу понять, почему именно `Observable`? То есть как я понимаю, чтобы выполнился запрос мы вызываем метод `subscribe(...)`, данные придут в `onNext()`, затем произойдет вызов `onCompleted()`. И получается `onNext()` вызовется всего 1 раз. Чтобы сделать повторный запрос, нам снова приходится вызывать `subscribe(...)`, и сценарий повторяется. Я знаю, что при использовании `Observable`'а вызов `onNext()` может происходить 0, 1, 2, ..., n раз. Но в данном случае получается, что мы имеем 2 подписчика и у каждого `onNext()` выполнился по 1 разу. А это по сути поведение `Single`. Так почему же используют `Observable` или `Flowable`, а не `Single`?

Comment: Возможно кому-то так проще. Как правило результат запроса используется для других `Observable` и проще сразу иметь `Observable`, чем кажды раз добавлять `.toObservable()`. Я в проектах всегда использую `Single`